# JSON at line 1 column 3

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here's the command, formatted what I thoughtwas correctly...

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"This map is based off of 1.9 features such as detecting when you pick up items,","color":"green"},{"text":" [HINT] ","color":"dark_green","bold":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tellraw @p {{\"text\":\"[HINT]\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\"},{\"text\":\"This pickaxe cannot break lit glowstone lamps.\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"}}"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Click For Hint"}]}}},{"text":"so you may need to think outside of the box for some levels. good Luck!","color":"green"}]
```

However it's giving me `Invalid json: malformed JSON at line 1 column 3` Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix 'Invalid JSON' errors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304990/how-do-i-fix-invalid-json-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Your clickEvent value starts with two curly brackets instead of a square followed by a curly.

However, when a player clicks a clickEvent via `/tellraw`, they are running the `value` as if they have manually typed it into the chat themselves. This means that the player is subject to chat limitations, such as requiring OP to run commands as well as a 100-character limit. The command being run exceeds that character limit, so it is trimmed (causing an error due to invalid format as a result of the trim).

The solution is to either use a shorter command or to use a different command altogether. For example, [`/scoreboard`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#scoreboard) for OP'd players or [`/trigger`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#trigger) for non-OP'd players while using an external mechanism to target players with a changed score.

Example using /scoreboard:

The `/tellraw` command becomes:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"This map is based off of 1.9 features such as detecting when you pick up items,","color":"green"},{"text":" [HINT] ","color":"dark_green","bold":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players set @a[c=1] OBJ 1"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Click For Hint"}]}}},{"text":"so you may need to think outside of the box for some levels. good Luck!","color":"green"}]
```

(clickEvent value specifically being):

```
/scoreboard players set @a[c=1] OBJ 1
```

External command sending a new /tellraw command to players with an OBJ score of 1:

```
/tellraw @a[score_OBJ_min=1] [{"text":"[HINT]","color":"dark_blue"},{"text":"This pickaxe cannot break lit glowstone lamps.","color":"light_purple"}]
```

Afterwards, set the player to have an OBJ score of 0 to prevent constant spam:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_OBJ_min=1] OBJ 0
```